# How can we update a DStream

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

How can I update a DStream in a micro-batch between stages and use the last modified DStream in new batch?
I used `updateStateByKey`, but it cannot maintain updated DStream in last stage in new batch. `mapWithState` also, is not my solution.

I want a mutable RDD like `List` in java to add and remove from it.

Comment: what is that you want to do? what problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: I have a key list. some keys add to it from input (kafkaStream). it will update in each batch. some keys removed during processing stages. the  rdd in last stage is updated rdd that i need to it in new batch. in current state using `updateStateByKey` my key list is only growing. i cannot remove from it based last update.

Comment: You can use mapWithState for that, what problems did you find when using it?

Comment: I need to evaluate all keys. in `updateStateByKey` i can do that but in `mapWithState` i can't. it just map over new values. it return mapped keys, but i need all keys.

Comment: @majidhajibaba you might try one of the many datastores that can connect to Spark to store your keys. One of them, [SnappyData](https://github.com/SnappyDataInc/snappydata), allows you to [mutate data directly from Spark](https://github.com/SnappyDataInc/snappydata/blob/master/docs/rowAndColumnTables.md#api-extensions-provided-in-snappycontext) as you request. Note, however, that this mutable data is a DataFrame and not a RDD.